# Reconhecimento de voz offline

Tags: android

Criei um aplicativo de automação que utiliza o reconhecimento de voz.

Testei em outro celular e ele não funciona sem ter internet ativa, sei que esse erro está relacionado a versão do Android.

A alguma alternativa para burlar isso? Pensei em um `EditText` e quando direcionar o foco habilitaria a tecla de voz (a do teclado, pois funciona offline), porém não sei se é possível desabilitar o teclado e ir direto para a voz de forma automática.

Comment: Não entendi direito. Tipo.. você quer um reconhecimento de voz offline que seja ativado quando o usuário clicar em um `EditText`?

Comment: não não amigo ! para minha aplicação que usa comandos por voz tem que esta conectado a internert (para usar o servidor do google) porém eu não queria isso , queria de forma offline acho que versao acima de 4.1 do android ele não  da essa opção , gostaria de burlar isso e dei um exemplo usando o microfone que aparece no teclado virtual do android tem essa opção de forma off.. Entendeu agora ?

Comment: entendi... fui ver um exemplo que fiz aqui em um app meu que está na Google Play, e antes que funcionava normal offline, agora com o android LolliPop parou... rsrsrs. O único exemplo que tenho, é o tradicional que utiliza os serviços da Google. Eu lembro que antes funcionava sem internet, pois fazia testes, mas agora parece que não. Mesmo assim se desejar me avisa que coloco o exemplo aqui.

Comment: Se eu descobrir alguma alternativa eu postarei o fonte!! mas valeu pela atenção.

Comment: @Tarione Dias Vocês conseguiram uma solução?